# php_mongo.dll class MongoClient is not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I am absolutely new in php and mongodb!
 The problem is that I got an error : class MongoClient is not found.
 My platform is Windows 8 32 bit and it seems that what I need is php_mongo.dll 32 bit too.

I am trying to find this dll but it's unhelpful. So maybe somebody knows where I can find this dll.

Thanks a lot , Roman.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php Read this

Comment: Thanks. All these I have done already, but it does not help